# How to swith the active class assigned to the li element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I found several topics here on SoF with the same problem, however in my case nothing works. Please help me find the mistake. Here is the code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<script>
    $('.nav.navbar-nav li').click(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $("li.active").removeClass("active");
            $this.addClass("active");
        }

    });
</script>
```

also I tried this:

```
 $('.nav.navbar-nav li a').click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: you want to change class to active ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove class from all `li` and then add to one that is clicked.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WQ47b/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav.navbar-nav li').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('li.active').removeClass("active"); 
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is work in the fiddle. If I copy this to my page, it doesn't work. I have jquery-1.9.1.min.js linked

Comment: I found the problem! My script was placed before the html code! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest`  or `parent` selector  to select immediate parent

```
    $('.nav.navbar-nav li a').click(function (e) {
            var $this = $(this).closest("li");
            if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
});
```

or

```
 $('.nav.navbar-nav li').click(function () {

        $(this).closest(".nav.navbar-nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");


    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WQ47b/2/)

Comment: Thank you for the code. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code `$this` is not defined.

Try the below code

```
$('.nav.navbar-nav li').click(function () {
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8763Z/)**